# Howto clear every created dynamically objects c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating BitmapImages, to download images from IP cam.

I use `DownloadCompleted`, `DownloadFailed` and `DownloadProgress` events.

But every hour, I reset everything. Those images are created dynamically, and I'd like to clear them (or destroy them) when I reset. But I don't find them, and they continue to fire the events....
Here the example :

```
void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BitmapImage img = New BitmapImage();
    img.BeginInit();
    img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
    img.UriCachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
    img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
    img.DownloadCompleted += DownloadCompleted; 
    img.DownloadFailed += DownloadFailed; 
    img.DownloadProgress += bi_DownloadProgress;
    img.UriSource = new Uri(xR["URLJPG"].ToString());
//xR["URLJPG"] is a DataViewRow, that contains the url to download for each image)
    img.EndInit();
}
```

There is several images created this way. I'd like to clear ou destroy them all.

Comment: What do you do when you reset everything?

Comment: It keeps firing events. So if I could destroy or juste remove the eventhandler of theses images... That could do the trick

Comment: But what do YOU do? How do you reset everything? The only code you show is a timer callback event. I don't see any reset.

Comment: thoses images are added to image controls. I remove them from the main windows when I reset. I also reset the DataView. The point is, I'd like to destroy thoses images, because they stay in the heap, which causes my program to take more and more memory

Comment: In your event handler unsubscribe from the item, this is a common memory leak. `img.DownloadCompleted -= DownloadCompleted;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't entirely solve my problem, but contribute to it.

Comment: What do you mean? BTW you have to tag my name in so I can get a notification about your comment, to tag me you need to type '@' and then my username.

Comment: @XAMIMAX : I mean that it does not destroy the image object. It just remove the eventhandler (wich is a very good start, after trying, it drops down my memory consumption by 50 percent) but the BitmapImage object is still here. I can't set "null" to "sender". Anyway, it's enough, because when all the eventhandler are removed, the garbage collector cleans everything up.

Comment: Weird I didn't get notified :/, however I would unsubscribe from Progress, failure and success when the image is finished also the same for failure if that is not against your requirements. After that your `img` object will get collected by the garbage collector anyway, like you said.